# Can I write a plugin for the Windows 8 "People" app?

Tags: plugins, windows-8, contacts

When I look at a contact in the Windows 8 "People" app, there are many different options that show up, depending on what data is available.

[image: contact example]

Some of these are built-in functions, but there are also some that call external programs, such as mapping an address, or linking to facebook.

Is this application extensible in that I might write a plugin to put another option on this page to link into my own app or website with the attached contact data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today, the built-in apps, like the People app, are not extensible.

Comment: That stinks.  But I guess it's the correct answer.  It's got me thinking though - if they did have this, how might it be implemented? Plugins usually have to be discovered (via MEF for example).  Since each app is in a sandbox, is there even an opportunity to design a Windows Store app that allows plugins?  Where would they go?

Comment: I'll have to think about that one more.  The plugins could be stored in the ApplicationData local folder and enumerated at startup.  I haven't played with dynamically loading code or reflection in any depth (i.e., at all) so not sure of the challenges there.

Comment: Internally Windows Runtime infrastructure provides a fairly flexible extension catalog - that's how sharing contracts and background tasks (and even activation) work. If such an extension mechanism would be implemented in the future, it would leverage the extension catalog.

Comment: I agree with Jeff about them going in ApplicationData. You could use MEF for this, but you'll have to get MEF to enumerate your own custom plugin folder into a catalog. You'll also need to work out your own delivery system for plugins since you wouldn't be able to use a standard desktop installer. This could be a simple WebClient download, but the point is you'd need to get it there somehow if it's not packaged with your solution. MEF support for Windows Store apps is fairly recent, but it's there. http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/12/20/mef-for-windows-store-apps.aspx